# Erro exibir atributo chave estrangeira

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Tenho as minhas classes:

```
public class Bandeira
{
    public int BandeiraID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}

public class Curso
{
    public int CursoID { get; set; }
    public virtual int BandeiraID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bandeira Bandeira { get; set; }
}
```

O método do meu repositório:

```
 public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate, string[] includes)
    {
        var query = GetAll().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            query = query.Include(include);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Meu Controller:

```
  var bdCurso = new CursoRepositorioEF(contexto);
  var curso = bdCurso.Get(x => x.CursoID == id, new string[] { "Bandeira" }).FirstOrDefault();
  bdCurso.Dispose();
  if (curso == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
  return View(curso);
```

Então minha View:

```
@model Aplicacao.Core.Dominio.Curso

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CursoID)

    @Html.Display("teste", Model.Bandeira.Nome, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
}
```

Gera o seguinte erro na View:

> An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed
>   and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua *View* possivelmente faz carga preguiçosa de alguma coisa em seu objeto, por isso a exigência de o contexto existir até a completa renderização da *View*.

O `dispose` manual não é necessário, visto que ele é feito sozinho ao fim da execução da `Action` no `Controller`.